# Hadoop is allowing to create a same directory concurrently

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, mkdir

When I am trying to create a directory in hdfs using python with multiprocessing, suppose if I am having 10 instances trying to create hdfs directory, expectation is that out of 10 only 1 instance should succeed in creating directory and remaining instances should fail saying "directory exists". But if you run the below mentioned code, you could notice that more than once it's succeeded.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
def dir_create(n):
    check = os.system("hadoop fs -mkdir /user/vamsi")
    print(str(n), "---", check)

p = Pool(5)
p.map(dir_create, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Here if check=0, success.
Please help in getting a solution that in only one instance directory will be created and in remaining instances it should fail.

Comment: Is it native HDFS ?

Comment: It's an AWS EMR Cluster.

Comment: And HDFS is actually S3?

Comment: No. Both are different.